# OPENCL API's take almost same time irrespective of sample size

Tags: macos, profiling, opencl, hpc

I've been trying to profile an OpenCL host code for FIR filtering on MAC, Ubuntu and other platforms. My Host code and kernel are as below.

The issue is that irrespective of the number of samples that I provide for the FIR filter, the clenquendrangelernel ends up taking the same amount of time. Also I've profiled the clEnqueueReadBuffer and clEnqueueWriteBuffer as well and somehow they also end up taking the same amount of time. In mac I'm profiling with mach as well as using OpenCL events, in ubuntu, I'm profiling with PAPI. Im unable to understand why this is happening, ideally with increase in the number of samples, the clEnqueueReadBuffer and clEnqueueWriteBuffer should take more time and so should kernel execution.

Kernel:-

```
__kernel void fir4(                                                     
    __global float* input,                                              
    __global float* output)                                           
{                                                                     
   int i = get_global_id(0); 
   int j = 0;
   int coeff[4] = {5,7,5,7};
   /*for(j=0;j<4;j++)
   {
    output[i] += coeff[j]*(input[i+4-j-1]);
   }*/
   //unrolled 
   output[i] += coeff[0]*(input[i+4-0-1]);
   output[i] += coeff[1]*(input[i+4-1-1]);
   output[i] += coeff[2]*(input[i+4-2-1]);
   output[i] += coeff[3]*(input[i+4-3-1]);                             
}  


__kernel void fir8(                                                     
    __global float* input,                                              
    __global float* output)                                           
{                                                                     
   int i = get_global_id(0); 
   int j = 0;
   int coeff[8] = {5,7,5,7,5,7,5,7};
   for(j=0;j<8;j++)
   {
    output[i] += coeff[j]*(input[i+8-j-1]);
   }                                
}    


__kernel void fir12(                                                     
    __global float* input,                                              
    __global float* output)                                           
{                                                                     
   int i = get_global_id(0); 
   int j = 0;
   int coeff[12] = {5,7,5,7,5,7,5,7,5,7,5,7};
   for(j=0;j<12;j++)
   {
    output[i] += coeff[j]*(input[i+12-j-1]);
   }                                
}
```

Host Code:-

```
// Use a static data size for simplicity
//
#define DATA_SIZE (48000)
#define NUM_COEFF (4)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    uint64_t        start;
    uint64_t        end;
    uint64_t        elapsed;
    double        elapsedmilli;

    int err;                            // error code returned from api calls

    float data[DATA_SIZE];              // original data set given to device
    float coeff[NUM_COEFF];
    float results_host[DATA_SIZE] = {};
    float results[DATA_SIZE];           // results returned from device
    unsigned int correct;               // number of correct results returned

    size_t global;                      // global domain size for our calculation
    size_t local;                       // local domain size for our calculation

    cl_event event;                     //Linking event to kernel for profiling
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;  // compute device platform id
    cl_device_id device_id;             // compute device id 
    cl_context context;                 // compute context
    cl_command_queue commands;          // compute command queue
    cl_program program;                 // compute program
    cl_kernel kernel;                   // compute kernel

    cl_mem input;                       // device memory used for the input array
    cl_mem output;                      // device memory used for the output array

    // Fill our data set with random float values
    //
    int i,j = 0;
    unsigned int count = DATA_SIZE;
    unsigned int taps = NUM_COEFF;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        data[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;

    for(i=0; i < taps; i++)
    {
        if(!(i%2))
            coeff[i] = 5;
        else
            coeff[i] = 7;
    }



    //Connect to a platform on device
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to locate opencl platform!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Connect to a compute device
    //
    int gpu = 0;
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, gpu ? CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a device group!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Create a compute context 
    //
    context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
    if (!context)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a compute context!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Create a command commands
    //
    commands = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);
    if (!commands)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create a command commands!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //Use function and load the kernel source from .cl files in the same folder
    //
    char *KernelSource = load_program_source("fir.cl");

    // Create the compute program from the source buffer
    //
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) & KernelSource, NULL, &err);
    if (!program)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute program!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Build the program executable
    //
    err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        size_t len;
        char buffer[2048];

        printf("Error: Failed to build program executable!\n");
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &len);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create the compute kernel in the program we wish to run
    //
    switch(taps)
    {
        case(4):
            {
                kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "fir4", &err);
                break;
            }
        case(8):
            {
                kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "fir8", &err);
                break;
            }
        case(12):
            {
                kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "fir12", &err);
                break;
            }
        default:
            {
                kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "fir4", &err);
                break;
            }
    }
    if (!kernel || err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to create compute kernel! - %d\n",err);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create the input and output arrays in device memory for our calculation
    //
    input = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  sizeof(float) * count, NULL, NULL);
    output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * count, NULL, NULL);
    if (!input || !output)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to allocate device memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }    
    // Write our data set into the input array in device memory 
    //
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commands, input, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * count, data, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to write to source array!\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    // Set the arguments to our compute kernel
    //
    err = 0;
    err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &input);
    err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to set kernel arguments! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Get the maximum work group size for executing the kernel on the device
    //
    err = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, device_id, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(local), &local, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to retrieve kernel work group info! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Execute the kernel over the entire range of our 1d input data set
    // using the maximum number of work group items for this device
    //
    global = count;
    local = 48;
    start = mach_absolute_time();
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commands, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, &local, 0, NULL, &event);
    if (err)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to execute kernel!-%d\n",err);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Wait for the command commands to get serviced before reading back results
    //
    clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
    clFinish(commands);
    end = mach_absolute_time();

    cl_ulong time_start, time_end;
    double total_time;
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
    total_time = time_end - time_start;
    printf("cl:main timing:opencl clEnqueueNDRangeKernel %0.3f us\n", total_time / 1000.0);

    elapsed = end - start;
    struct mach_timebase_info info;
    mach_timebase_info(&info);
    double t = 1e-9 * (elapsed) * info.numer / info.denom;
    elapsedmilli = 1e-6 * (elapsed) * info.numer / info.denom;
    printf("cl:main timing:MACH clEnqueueNDRangeKernel %f ms, %d elapsed\n",elapsedmilli,elapsed);

    // Read back the results from the device to verify the output
    //
    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer( commands, output, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * count, results, 0, NULL, NULL );  
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to read output array! %d\n", err);
        exit(1);
    }

    // Validate our results
    //
    correct = 0;
    for(i=0; i<DATA_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<NUM_COEFF;j++)
        {
            results_host[i]+=coeff[j]*(data[i+NUM_COEFF-j-1]);
        }
        //printf("Host Output[%d]-%f\n",i,results_host[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(results[i] == results_host[i])
            correct++;
        //printf("CL Output[%d]-%f\n",i,results[i]);
    }

    // Print a brief summary detailing the results
    //
    printf("Computed '%d/%d' correct values! Samples-%d,Taps-%d\n", correct, count, DATA_SIZE, NUM_COEFF);

    // Shutdown and cleanup
    //
    clReleaseMemObject(input);
    clReleaseMemObject(output);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(commands);
    clReleaseContext(context);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding just 10-20 multiplications and additions per item is not comparable to kernel overhead time. Try with 100 or 1000-wide coefficients array.

Using more input elements per item with that way, just increases cache hit numbers(also ratio) because more threads read from same locations.

If DATA_SIZE is several millions, then all data could not fit in cache and become slower linearly with its length. 48000 means less than 200kB.  A HD5850 has  512 k L2 cache(3x bandwidth of memory) and 8kB L1 per compute unit(too fast) for example.